# How to check hasClass in html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I create tables and I would like to check whether each element `hasClass` by clicking correcponding cells(above cells)

My work is like below.

But it didn't work well.

How can I achieve it ?

And What is wrong point?

Thanks

```js
$("td.number").click(function(){
  id=$(this).index();
  $("td.color").index(id).hasClass("aqua");
  });
```

```css
td {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.number{
cursor:pointer;}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.color{
 padding:5px;
 }
 
.aqua {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=calendar></div>

<script>
let html = ''
html += '<table>';
let i = 0;

html += '<tr>';
for (let d = 0; d < 15; d++) {
  i = i + 1;
  html += '<td class="number">' + i +'</td>'
}
html += '</tr>';

for (let w = 0; w < 1; w++) {
  html += '<tr>';
  for (let d = 0; d < 15; d++) {
    html += '<td class="color"></td>'
    }
    html += '</tr>';
  }
html += '</table>'
document.querySelector('#calendar').innerHTML = html;

const arr = [1, 2, 10, 11, 14];

$("td.color")
  .filter(function() { return arr.includes($(this).index()+1); })
  .addClass('aqua');
</script>
```

Comment: Your use of `.index()` is incorrect - it's *only* for returning the index as an integer, not for find an element based on its index - for that you want `.eq()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.index()` is used to return the position as an integer, not to find an element based on its index - for that you want `.eq()`

Updated fiddle:

```js
$("td.number").click(function(){
  id=$(this).index();
  $(this).toggleClass("aqua", $("td.color").eq(id).hasClass("aqua"));
});
```

```css
td {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.number{
cursor:pointer;}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.color{
 padding:5px;
 }
 
.aqua {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=calendar></div>

<script>
let html = ''
html += '<table>';
let i = 0;

html += '<tr>';
for (let d = 0; d < 15; d++) {
  i = i + 1;
  html += '<td class="number">' + i +'</td>'
}
html += '</tr>';

for (let w = 0; w < 1; w++) {
  html += '<tr>';
  for (let d = 0; d < 15; d++) {
    html += '<td class="color"></td>'
    }
    html += '</tr>';
  }
html += '</table>'
document.querySelector('#calendar').innerHTML = html;

const arr = [1, 2, 10, 11, 14];

$("td.color")
  .filter(function() { return arr.includes($(this).index()+1); })
  .addClass('aqua');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your selector by making use of `eq()` and not `index()` to access the element you need:

```
$("td.number").click(function(){
  var id = $ (this).index();
  $("td.color").eq(id).hasClass("aqua");
});
```